# all possible paths in r

Tags: r, path

```
dt_original = tibble(
  level = c("10001","10001","10001","10002","10002","10003","10003","10003","10003","10003","10003"),
  code = c("L72.3","L70.0","L72.3","D23.5","L70.0","L40.0","L72.3","L70.0","L70.0","L72.3","L40.0")
)
```

Hi all, my dataframe has 3 levels and I need to find all combinations of code in the order of level. For example, "L72.3","D23.5","L40.0" is one path. "L72.3" from level 10001, "D23.5" from level 10002 and "L40.0" from level 10003. There are 3 of 10001 levels, 2 of 10002 levels and 6 of 10003 levels, so there are 3 times 2 times 6 = 36 total possible paths. At last I need one list containing all these 36 paths like ["L72.3","D23.5","L40.0"......] Appreciate if anyone can help.

Comment: Does the solution below solves your problem? If so, please click on "accept answer".

Answer (score 0):

You can do (inspired by @akrun‘s simplification of my previous code):

```
as.character(t(expand.grid(split(dt_original$code, dt_original$level))))

  [1] "L72.3" "D23.5" "L40.0" "L70.0" "D23.5" "L40.0" "L72.3" "D23.5" "L40.0"
 [10] "L72.3" "L70.0" "L40.0" "L70.0" "L70.0" "L40.0" "L72.3" "L70.0" "L40.0"
 [19] "L72.3" "D23.5" "L72.3" "L70.0" "D23.5" "L72.3" "L72.3" "D23.5" "L72.3"
 [28] "L72.3" "L70.0" "L72.3" "L70.0" "L70.0" "L72.3" "L72.3" "L70.0" "L72.3"
 [37] "L72.3" "D23.5" "L70.0" "L70.0" "D23.5" "L70.0" "L72.3" "D23.5" "L70.0"
 [46] "L72.3" "L70.0" "L70.0" "L70.0" "L70.0" "L70.0" "L72.3" "L70.0" "L70.0"
 [55] "L72.3" "D23.5" "L70.0" "L70.0" "D23.5" "L70.0" "L72.3" "D23.5" "L70.0"
 [64] "L72.3" "L70.0" "L70.0" "L70.0" "L70.0" "L70.0" "L72.3" "L70.0" "L70.0"
 [73] "L72.3" "D23.5" "L72.3" "L70.0" "D23.5" "L72.3" "L72.3" "D23.5" "L72.3"
 [82] "L72.3" "L70.0" "L72.3" "L70.0" "L70.0" "L72.3" "L72.3" "L70.0" "L72.3"
 [91] "L72.3" "D23.5" "L40.0" "L70.0" "D23.5" "L40.0" "L72.3" "D23.5" "L40.0"
[100] "L72.3" "L70.0" "L40.0" "L70.0" "L70.0" "L40.0" "L72.3" "L70.0" "L40.0"
```

Comment: It can be made compact `expand.grid(split(dt_original$code, dt_original$level))`

Comment: Thank you so much! By the way, is there anyway that I could make all these into one vector like [L72.3, D23.5 ,L40.0,L70.0 ,D23.5, L40.0....]? I tried split(df, seq(nrow(df))). However, I did not get what i want

Comment: See my update. This solutions doesn‘t require any package, and is only base R. If it solves your problem, please consider accepting it.